# How to convert float value into same NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

How I can convert float value in NSString but value should be same as float. If float f = 34.000 then NSString also have 34.000.

I want that my float value should not be changed whatever it have value of 2 decimal then string should be 2 decimal if it have 3 decimal also then string should be 3 decimal.

I used many concept but nothing help

Thanks

Comment: what teh output you expect

Comment: Not that this isn't a duplicate, but `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", floatValue]`.

Comment: if precision (number of 0) is important to you, use double instead of float. it's twice more precise. Now, from a mathematical point of view, the last 0 are unrelevant, if you want to strip them, use %g instead of %f. If you want to force a certain number of decimal after the '.' then force it with %.6f (float are precise to 6 digit, meaning from a float perspective 34.000001 = 34 )

Answer (score 4):

You can use `stringWithFormat`:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", myFloat];
```

what you must understand is that your float is not equal to 34.000 or 34.0... it is equal to {0x00 0x00 0x08 0x42} which can be represented in decimal as 34, 34.0, 34.0000000000 .... how you want to represent the value is up to you, and that what  %f is for : %.2f will display only 2 decimal after the .

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
float f = 34.0f;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", f];
```

(the `.3` will give you 3 decimal places)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
  let floatValye: Float = 0.1111
  let stringValue : String = String(format: "%.3f",floatValye)
```